# Solving Recursive Equations: How to transform the domain in such cases?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursive-algorithms

I understand that a widely-used recursive equation for the Binary Search is as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
T(1) &= 1\\
T(n) &= T(\tfrac{n}{2}) + 1, \quad n>1
\end{align}
$$

In order to solve the recursive equation we would simply transform the domain by setting $n = 2^k$, write the transformed equation, go through the telescoping and all that good stuff...

Anyway, my professor said that sometimes there may be an odd number of elements in a sorted list, in which case the equation would look like:
$$
\begin{align}
T(1) &= 1\\
T(n) &= T(\tfrac{n-1}{2}) + 1,\quad n>1
\end{align}
$$

**Then I wondered, how would I perform a domain transformation on such an equation?**

Thank you very much!

Comment: Presumably by $T(n-1/2)$ you mean $T((n-1)/2)$.  Please use proper parentheses as what you wrote is $T(n-(1/2))$.  Even better, as it is easier to read, $T(\frac {n-1}2)$  For $\LaTeX$ you can see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

In the case that $n$ is an odd number, we can just use $n=2k+1$. You'll end up with
$$T(2k+1)=T\left(\frac{2k+1-1}{2}\right)+1$$
I'll let you take care of the rest.